# Internal storage to SD card issues

Tags: internal-storage

I have an Alcatel-4060A mobile and the internal storage is forever full. I only have two games and maybe 4 pics downloaded. Since I buy an 8 GB sd card. It only lets me download 4 apps on sd . Also says I'VE still got 7.28GB free on sd card. Won't let me download anymore apps. Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

From the settings you will have to go to storage settings and then you will have to enable the **sd card storage** which would probably allow you to install all the apps and other downloads easily on sd card nd I would also prefer to buy an card with larger space in it.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if there is an option "format sd-card as internal" or similar. If you enable it the storage of your device and the sd-card will be joined.

WARNING: One you format your sd-card as internal memory you will no longer be able to remove or replace the sd-card. Removing the sd-card will cause a (complete) data loss!